# Why is "cursor:pointer" effect in CSS not working

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

I set `cursor: pointer` for `.about > span`, but when my mouse hovers on those texts in `<span>`, the cursor does not change into pointer mode. I would like to know why it is not working.

```css
#firstdiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

.about>span {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Eurofurence Light;
  padding: 0 0 3px 0;
  color: #01DFA5;
}
```

```html
<div id="firstdiv">
  <div id="intro">
    <h1 id="name">YOU CHIA LAI</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="about">I am a Master of <span>Architecture</span> candidate at Rice University.
      </li>
      <li class="about">I am also interested in <span>photography</span> &
        <span>web design</span>.</li>
      <li class="about">I wish you can know more <span>about</span> me.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `z-index:-2` from `#firstdiv` and have a look at [why you shouldn't just paste a link to your demo page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/217025).

Comment: Strangely worked with me, would be something with `z-index`, in which browser this failure happens? +1 for @MarcelGwerder

Comment: The answer below fixed this for me, but closing and reopening chrome.

Comment: For people with it set, `pointer-events: none` will also stop `cursor` from having an effect.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You need to change the z-index so that `#firstdiv` is considered on top of the other divs.

Comment: batter ans is  ==>  : pointer-events: none;  <===  not need to Z-index

Comment: @lalitbhakuni that is incorrect and actually prevents the cursor from changing altogether...

Answer (score 513):

I messed with my css for hours, changing the positioning and z-index of just about every element on the page. I deleted every other element from the DOM except for the one with the cursor: pointer on hover, and it STILL didn't work.

For me, on Mac OSX El Captain V 10.11, the issue had to do with some sort of interference with Photoshop CC. Once I closed Photoshop, the cursor started working again.

**Solution for me:** Close and reopen Photoshop

Apparently this can happen due to many different programs including Photoshop, Sketch, DataGrip, Acrobat, Sublime Text, etc.

---

Update (11/18/2023): If you ever experience the issue where your cursor doesn't change to indicate you can drag to resize an application window on MacOS, this may be the culprit.

Comment: This was happening to me in all browsers in OS X (chrome, safari, firefox). Started closing programs, one by one, until I found out that it was Sublime Text 3 in full-screen mode on a second screen that was causing this issue to happen. This answer, however, has nothing to do with original question.

Comment: I saw this highly-upvoted solution and thought it was some kind of mistake because what does another program have to do with my CSS in the browser not working correctly. But, sure enough, closing Photoshop (2022 version in my case) immediately resolved the issue. Glad I tried this before going down an unnecessary CSS tweaking rabbit hole.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been bugging me for years! Closing Photoshop helped!

Comment: I had the same issue right now with all my browsers, and Photoshop was the culprit!  Terrible coding from Adobe!  Thanks for submitting this answer, as it was driving me round the bend!

Comment: In all my years of coding, this is the weirdest bug I've ever encountered. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Whoaaa! I can't believe this! Same here, I resolved the problem by closing Photoshop (thank you for this hint, it really saved me a ton of time!). Just an additional piece of information on top of your comment: the issue is happening on June 2022 with Photoshop `23.3.1`, and Google Chrome `102.0.5005.61` on a MacOS Monterey `12.4`. After closing and reopening Photoshop, the problem doesn't show again.

Comment: Can't believe this is still a bug in 2022. I can confirm that closing and re-opening Photoshop solved the issue on Macbook Pro (M1 chip)

Comment: Holy crap, this just happened to me on my MBP M1 Max. Was driving me crazy! Thank you!

Comment: I thought I was losing my mind. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: This did not work for me. I closed Sublime 3 (and Affinity Photo and a few others), no change. Seriously puzzling.

Comment: Man this was crazy! I was actually thinking "I can't believe I'm googling something so simple - it's definitely just some rogue element on the page" but glad I did now!

Comment: Still true in Feb 2023... Shame on you Adobe!

Comment: Can't believe there's such type of bug. I fixed this issue after closing Photoshop and Illustrator. My machine is MBP M1 Pro. Wow. Thanks for saving my time.

Comment: again saved my ass!

Comment: Dear lord, I've been trying to add a cursor on a box for hours... stupid photoshop messing everything up. *facepalm*

Comment: A good ol' restarting my computer fixed it for me.

Comment: That is completely crazy!

Comment: It was a figma prototype that was causing the glitch for me

Comment: Holy sh**. M1 Pro. Angular Project. Me I had to kill Finder + it was only interfering with my project. Totally Crazy ! [CMD+Option+Escape] -> restart Finder and Boom, back to normal

Comment: Wow ... who knows how many hours this response just saved me. Thank you!

Comment: In my case it was VS Code waiting for a restart for an update.

Comment: Incredible, still happening with PS 2024. Thankfully this post was one of the first and I only lost 10 mins to it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 46):

Just happened to me, and in my case it was due to a CSS rule `pointer-events: none;` which was set on a parent element and I forgot about it.

This caused any pointer events to be just ignored, which includes the cursor.

To fix this, you can just set the style to allow pointer events:

```
.about>span{
    cursor:pointer;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Or directly in the element:

```
<span style="pointer-events: auto;">...</span>
```

Comment: pointer-events: auto fixed the cursor pointer, but it no longer triggers the expected action on click

Answer (score 36):

`cursor:pointer` doesn't work when you're using Chrome's mobile emulator.

[image]

Comment: I believe that's intentional or at least expected behavior as there is no cursor on a mobile device, except perhaps for text selection and that's OS dependent and not sure you can override that.

Comment: I had the same issue once in chrome (But not in mobile emulator). So i turn "mobile emulator" on and off and chrome get back to the right stage. ;-D

Answer (score 7):

Also add cursor:hand. Some browsers need that instead.

Comment: [Are you really talking and caring about IE 5/5.5?](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/cursor.html#t013)

Comment: Or hybrid browsers which have been based around IE5...like used in some large companies. Have I really been voted down 3 times for this!? Not impressed really, shame on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

```
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
cursor: pointer
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For the last few hours, I was scratching my head why my CSS wasn't working! I was trying to show `row-resize` as cursor but it was showing the default cursor but for `s-resize` browser was showing the correct cursor. I tried changing `z-index` but that also didn't solve my problem.

So after trying few more solutions from the internet, I called one of my co-workers and shared my screen via Google meet and he told me that he was seeing the row-resize icon when I was seeing the default icon!!! He even sent me the screenshot of my screencast.

So after further investigation, I found out the as I was using Remote Desktop Connection to connect to my office PC, for some reason RDC doesn't show some type of cursors.

Here is the list of cursor's I couldn't see on my remote PC,

`none, cell, crosshair, text, vertical-text, alias, copy, col-resize, row-resize,`

Answer (score 2):

It works if you remove `position:fixed` from `#firstdiv` - but @Sj is probably right as well - most likely a z-index layering issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue using Angular and SCSS. I had all my CSS nested so I decided to remove `cursor: pointer;` out of it. And it worked.

Example:

```
.container{
  .Approved{
    color:green;
  }

  .ApprovedAndVerified{
    color:black;
  }

  .lock_button{
    font-size:35px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
  }
}

.lock_button{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that the `:after` blocked mouse events, so I had to add `pointer-events: none;` to my `:after` block.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, when I close the chrome window popup browser inspector its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is using forward slash instead of backslash when 'calling' out from a local directory.

instead of backslash:

```css
cursor: url("C:\Users\Ken\projects\JavascriptGames\images\bird.png"), auto;
```

Note: When I use backslash I am getting a net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I changed it to forwardslash:

```css
cursor: url("C:/Users/Ken/projects/JavascriptGames/images/bird.png"), auto;
```

Note: When I use forward slash, the custom cursor style executes successfully.

This behavior regarding backslashes and forward slashes could probably be explained in this StackOverflow answer: [Strange backslash and behavior in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558601/strange-backslash-and-behavior-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was using `cursor: 'pointer'` mistakenly instead of `cursor: pointer`.
So, make sure you are not adding single or double quotes around pointer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I had this set globally:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

After removing this, `cursor: pointer` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove parent z-index value fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, the cursor will not change unless you set the style against :hover

this needs to be as follows, in addition to the class you already have for the elements.

```
.about > span:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, MacBook Air 2020, I found that I just needed to restart my computer, and then the `cursor: pointer` worked again on the web pages I was developing.

Looks like I either had too many chrome tabs open, or maybe an issue with my Adobe Illustrator that I had open, or my [AltTab](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/) app I had running. I can't nor have time to pin down which app was the culprit. But suffice to say, I just needed to restart my computer to get css `cursor: pointer` to work again.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution: use `:hover` with `cursor: pointer` if nothing else helps.

Answer (score -1):

Prevent user from selecting text, then use `curser:pointer` property -

```
.targeted-span{
user-select: none;
curser : pointer;}
```

Answer (score -2):

Position the element as relative and then use `z-index`

```
.menu-toggle{ 
    display: block; 
    width: 40px; 
    height: 40px; 
    border:2px solid white; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    margin: 15px; 
    float: right; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 30px; 
    color: var(--light-bg-color); 
    z-index: 10; 
}
```