# Tailwind - Links do not have the default cursor pointer on hover

Tags: tailwind-css

We use Tailwind CSS in our project. Any <a href*> tag should by default change the mouse pointer to cursor:pointer. In our normal HTML designs, this works fine, but when converted to ReactJS, all links display the normal cursor, and not the pointer.

So, I want to force the cursor:pointer to a-href elements in the Tailwind output style.css. I tried:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
    a {
        @apply cursor-pointer;
    }
}
```

That did not work. When inspecting any link element in chrome, I do not see `cursor: pointer` in the css for `<a href*>` tags.

[image: chrome styles]

This is weird because I fiddled in the tailwind playground and it worked, but not in my project:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/d3rpFZd6gM?file=css

Comment: I even had the issue on the playground you linked. On macOS, another program was the cause for me. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35212344/860205

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

a {
    @apply cursor-pointer;
}
```

Comment: I did. It added nothing to the link css properties. Really weird.

Answer (score 0):

I was going crazy knowing that the tailwind playground was working and my project was not. So, I tailwind to the latest version and it worked like a charm.